# Objective-C ASCII decimal integer to NSString conversion

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ascii

How can I convert and ASCII decimal integer to an NSString in Objective-C?  (Example: 36 to "$")

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 36];
NSLog(@"%@", s); // $
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
unichar asciiChar = 36;
NSString *stringWithAsciiChar = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&asciiChar length:1];
```